# Issues in using jfilechooser

Tags: java, swing, web-applications, jfilechooser

I am using `JFileChooser` in my web project  so that the client can download certain files from the server, But during testing whenever i click on the button that invokes the `jfilechooser` it pops up on the server system and not on the client system ,why is this happening and how do i solve it, Below is the code i have used.

```
JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
jfc.setDialogTitle("Enter the path to save .pdf file");
jfc.setFileView(new FileView() {
jfc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
jfc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
int status = jfc.showDialog(null, "OK");
```

Comment: Do you intend to let client browse your server file system?

Comment: No i am using the jfilechooser for the client to give the path to store the file inside client system

Comment: That's because the code exiting the file chooser is been executed on the server. You would need to use an applet to get it to run on the client, but they wouldn't be able to see the files on the server

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do the same in my web app, and also tried frist with JFileChooser, also got the problem as you. Then I solved this other way using "content - disposition". How it works: User click on button/link in my app, controller fetches something from database and write it to outputstream. User is asked if he wants to open this file or save it on computer. Here is how I done that in my app:

```
@Controller
public class ExportPhonebook extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Autowired
private PhoneBookService phoneBookSer;

private void setResponseHeaderTXT(HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setContentType("text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
    response.setHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=imenik.txt" );
} 

@RequestMapping(value = "/exportPhonebook.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void exportPhonebook(Model model, HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) {

    List<User> listOfAllUsers = phoneBookSer.fetchAllUsers();
    String imenik = "";

    for (User user : listOfAllUsers) {
        imenik = imenik + user.getPrezime() + " " + user.getIme() + ", Organizacijska jedinica: " + user.getOrganizacijskaJedinica() + 
        ", Telefon: " + user.getTelefon() + ", Faks: " + user.getTelefaks() + ", Email: " + user.getEmail() +
         ", Lokacija: " + user.getLokacija() + ", Kat: " + user.getKat() + ", Soba: " + user.getBrojSobe() + ";\r\n" ;
    }


        try {
            setResponseHeaderTXT(response);
            OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
            outputStream.write(imenik.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

I have done similar thing with pdf files:

```
@Controller
public class ExportPhonebook extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Autowired
private PhoneBookService phoneBookSer;

private void setResponseHeaderPDF(HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=imenik.pdf" );
} 

@RequestMapping(value = "/exportPhonebook.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void exportPhonebook(Model model, HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) {

        try {
            setResponseHeaderPDF(response);
            Document document = new Document();
            ByteArrayOutputStream baosPDF = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            PdfWriter pdfWriter = null;
            pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baosPDF);
            PageNumbersEventHelper events = new PageNumbersEventHelper();
            pdfWriter.setPageEvent(events);

            document.open();
            addMetaData(document);
            addTitlePage(document);
            ServletContext servletContext = request.getSession().getServletContext();

            String relativeWebPath = "img/image.png";
            String absoluteDiskPath = servletContext.getRealPath(relativeWebPath);
            Image image = Image.getInstance(absoluteDiskPath);
            image.setAbsolutePosition(450, 700);
            document.add(image);
            addContent(document);
            document.close();
            pdfWriter.close();
            OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
            baosPDF.writeTo(os);
            os.flush();
            os.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't copy several methods in which I create content for my pdf file, but I think that you don't need that.

Comment: Thx eveyrone i fixed it in an alternative way

Comment: @ferenit: how didi u fix it. please post it. I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: @1355 I didn't. The client later decided not to have the functionality